# KAA standalone Installation, unable to start Service on Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: digital-ocean, vps, kaa

I have followed all the steps as per the instructions. All the key services are running like zookeeper, mongodb. I have verified mutliple times.

However when it comes to start kaa-node, then service always fails with exit code.
I have verified several items including IP address etc on the Digital Ocean VPS. Validated the firewall setup.

Answer (score 0):

That might be caused by lack of necessary resources like memory or disk space. Please check the minimal requirements on the [Getting started](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Getting-started/) documentation page.

If that is not an issue, please provide more details on the error and logs you get from the kaa-node startup.